# Kill process when father process ends with Control+C

Tags: c, linux, process

I have a program with two processes. One of them could terminate or exit because an exception. While i'm testing the program I finish it using Control+c but the child process is still running.

Is there any option to kill the process when I push control+c or when the father process terminates.

Comment: You can catch control + c (SIGINT), and in signal handler you can kill child process..But for what?

Answer (score 6):

There's no option to automate this however you can code your applications to support it. A pre-requisite is that the process which wants the other to terminate must have its process id; this is the value the parent receives back from a `fork()` call.

Give each process a signal handler for `SIGINT` - when control-C is pressed, `SIGINT` is sent to the process. In this signal handler, send the signal to your other process and then `exit()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can start a listener on the child process that periodically checks whether the parent process is still running.

Comment: Polling is evil if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the answers you need **[here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement)**.
For instance, you can **trap** the CTRL+C and run a sub function on the **SIGINT** signal, that manages the way you want to exit or **kill** the running PID(s).

non functional example to illustrate the principle

```
SIGINT=2
trap 'clean_exit' $SIGINT
# other thgs in your main prog
function clean_exit(){
   # define SIGTERM and your $pid according to your need
   kill -$SIGTERM $pid
   #other things to  do
}
```

Comment: The 'trap' part could be written much cleaner, with no extra variable: `trap 'clean_exit' INT`.